# Running code based off of variable pulled in from excell sheet.

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

I'm trying to run code based off of a cell being pulled in from my excel sheet. My code runs but then it stops at the if statement. If statement below.

if(data03 == "Checkpoint")

java

Comment: use `.equals` to compare strings not `==`

Comment: try `if(data03.equals("Checkpoint"));`

Comment: Do you know how debugging Java code works? If not, try to learn that because it will give you more information which you can place in your questions (for example "`data03` has the value 'Checkpoint' but the if body still is not executed").

Answer (score 1):

Try :-

```
if ("Checkpoint".equals(data03)) { }
```

For String comparisons `.equals()` function is used in java. Not `==`. The  `==` just compares object references. `.equals()` tests for equality.

[For more Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: `if ("Checkpoint".equals(data03)) { }` is better as it prevents a possible NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusK. Great information. I have made the change.